# empty space after stopwords removal and lemmatisation

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

The text looks like this before processing

```
0   [It's, good, for, beginners]                        positive
1   [I, recommend, this, starter, Ukulele, kit., I...   positive
```

After preprocessing with `stopword` removal and lemmatisation

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['ner', 'parser']) # disabling Named Entity Recognition for speed

def cleaning(doc):
    txt = [token.lemma_ for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
    if len(txt) > 2:
        return ' '.join(txt)
brief_cleaning = (re.sub("[^A-Za-z']+", ' ', str(row)).lower() for row in df3['reviewText'])

txt = [cleaning(doc) for doc in nlp.pipe(brief_cleaning, batch_size=5000, n_threads=-1)]
```

the result came like this

```
0   ' good ' ' ' ' beginner '                       positive
1   ' ' ' recommend ' ' ' ' starter ' ' ukulele ... positive
```

As you can see, there are lots of `' '` in the result, what caused this? I'm assuming it's the `return ' '.join(txt)` and `re.sub("[^A-Za-z']+", ' '` that caused it, but if I removed the space or use `return (txt)`, it simply won't remove any `stopword` or carry out lemmatisation.

Will these empty space cause troubles, or are they necessary, because I'm doing bigram and `word2vec` afterwards.

How can I fix it and have the result returned as `' recommend '  ' starter ' ' ukulele ' ' kit '  ' need '  ' learn ' ' ukulele '`?

Comment: Not really sure what's going wrong here, but I would just note that you really don't need to remove stopwords or lemmatize text for modern NLP methods, including word2vec. You can just use the raw text.